# Display Contact Addressee as {prefix} {Initial} {last_name}

Tags: contacts

Hopefully self explanitory.

I want to extract the initial from the first name (if there is one) e.g. Mr John Smith appears as Mr J Smith as default.

Would be grateful for any help on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the 'Individual Display Name Format' in display preference to include {initial} token through custom extension using [tokens](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokens/) and [tokenvalues](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_tokenValues/) hook.

If you don't want to store this in the database and just alter the display on screen then you can use [contact_get_displayname](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_contact_get_displayname/) hook to alter the display name.

Pradeep